# Salesforce file drop/upload using webdriver

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Test case

To verify the file upload option in the salesforce application.
I'm trying to test the above test case with automating by using selenium Web driver.

but I'm getting an error (unable to upload the file)

upload screenshot attached please refer and let me know how can I upload a file by using selenium web driver

[image]
Aura component

Comment: what have you done so far? I'd [edit] and add in what you're doing in your code.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves WebElement fileInput = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='slds-file-selector__button slds-button slds-button_neutral']"))
fileInput.click()
fileInput.sendKeys("D:/data.json")

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I tried above code but I'm getting org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException

Comment: Please [edit] your question post with that code info. This is not my specialty, but it'll be helpful for others to provide assistance.